# How do you work with multiple udp channels in reactor netty?

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

I m trying to learn Reactor Netty so that I can reimplement a previous project that uses NIO selector for approximately 30 DatagramChannels and their multicasts. I would like to ask how to handle the creation of multiple UDPClient or Server? The created connections will be for listening then logging and persisting all the received data.

I am looking through the reactor netty reference guide, but it doesnt really mention anything on making multiple connections and how handling should be done. I m not sure if I can just wrap the sample code from the reference guide in a for loop, as the javadoc says `connection.onDispose().block()` is supposed to block indefinitely until the channel is shutdown/has error.

```
public class Main {
    public static String[] multicasts = {"239.2.1.0" ,"239.2.1.1", "239.2.1.2"};
    public static int[] ports = {55000, 55001, 55002};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NetworkInterface ni;
        try {
            ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
            
            Connection connection =
                    UdpClient.create()
                             .host(multicasts[0])
                             .port(ports[0])
                             .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new MulticastHandler()))
                             .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                             .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1500*20)
                             .option(ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ni)
                             .connectNow(Duration.ofSeconds(30)); //.handle((udpInbound, udpOutbound) -> udpInbound.receive().then()) 

            connection.onDispose()
                      .block();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}

//left over code from experimenting with Netty
class MulticastHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>{
//    private MoldUdpHeader moldUdpHeader = new MoldUdpHeader();
    AttributeKey<String> markerKey = AttributeKey.valueOf("Marker");  
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket) throws Exception {
        //do some decoding upon receiving a bytebuffer
//        moldUdpHeader.decode(datagramPacket.content().nioBuffer(), 0);
        //add decoded content (sequence number) to a list of lists
        
        //log out contents after decoding
//        System.out.println(channelHandlerContext.channel().attr(markerKey).get()+" "+moldUdpHeader.getSeqNum());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to wait until it closes (it's that's even applicable to a UDP client) just don't do `connection.onDispose().block()`

Comment: "_if that's even_"